# Insert-mode gqip not idempotent?

Tags: insert-mode, formatting

I open Vim and add the following lines to a buffer (call this state INITIAL):

```
xx xx xxx xx xxxx xx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxx xxx xxxx xxx x
xx xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xx x xxx xx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxx xx xxx xxx xx
xx xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxx xx xx xxxx xxxx xxx xx
xx xxxx xx x xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xx xxxx x xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
xx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx
```

I then go to the end of the buffer and enter insert mode (`GA`). I then type `<C-O>gqip`. The buffer changes to (call this state A):

```
xx xx xxx xx xxxx xx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxx xxx xxxx xxx x xx
xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xx x xxx xx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxx xx xxx xxx xx xx
xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxx xx xx xxxx xxxx xxx xx xx
xxxx xx x xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xx xxxx x xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xx
xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx
```

Still in insert mode, I type `<C-O>gqip` again. The buffer changes to (call this state B):

```
xx xx xxx xx xxxx xx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxx xxx xxxx xxx x xx
xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xx x xxx xx xxx xxxxxx xx xxxxxx xx xxx xxx xx xx
xxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxxx xx xx xxxx xxxx xxx xx xx
xxxx xx x xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx xx xxxx x xxxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxx
xx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx
```

Still in insert mode, I type `<C-O>gqip` again. The buffer changes back to A. It may be hard to tell, but A and B are actually distinct.  Still in insert mode, if I keep typing `<C-O>gqip`, the buffer state keeps toggling between A and B. The state progression is therefore INITIAL → A → B → A → B → A → B → ... .

When I try the above in normal mode, the state progression is INITIAL → A → A → A → A → ... (which is what I would expect).

(All of the above works if I use `gwip`, `gqap`, `gwap` in place of `gqip`.)

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there's some odd subtlety to Vim's commands that I've never noticed before.  I thought `gqip` was supposed to be idempotent no matter what mode I ran it from.

My question is: What is going on here?

(If you're wondering why all the text is `x`s, it's because I first noticed this behavior while working on some confidential code, and then replaced everything with `x`s so I could ask this question publicly.)

Comment: FWIW #1, the mode you are in after you press `<C-o>` in insert mode is called "insert normal mode". FWIW #2, there is no promise of idempotency made anywhere in the doc. FWIW #3, I think you have found a bug… that you should report.

Comment: @romainl Thank you, I've reported it to https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/22250 (not sure if I need to separately report it to the Vim repo).